# Why does `guarded False = fail "skipped"` type-checks?

Tags: haskell, monads, typechecking

I'm following the Real World Haskell book.  In the chapter about Monads, they give a simple example using the list monad to compute all pairs of numbers (x, y) that such that `x * y == n`.

Their solution is:

```
multiplyTo :: Int -> [(Int, Int)]
multiplyTo n = do
  x <- [1..n]
  y <- [x..n]
  guarded (x * y == n) $
    return (x, y)

guarded :: Bool -> [a] -> [a]
guarded True xs = xs
guarded False _ = []
```

But I was wondering if I could restate `guarded` for any monad.

Since `fail` in the list monad is `fail _ = []`, I though I could do:

```
guarded :: (Monad m) => Bool -> m a -> m a
guarded True = id
guarded False = fail "skipped"
```

However, this actually fails in ghci:

```
*Main> multiplyTo 24
*** Exception: skipped
```

I had a hunch which I cannot fully explain.  These two version work:

```
guarded :: (Monad m) => Bool -> m a -> m a
guarded True = id
guarded False = \s -> fail "skipped"

guarded :: (Monad m) => Bool -> m a -> m a
guarded True xs = xs
guarded False _ = fail "skipped"
```

The type of `fail "skipped"` is `Monad m => m a`, whereas the type of `guarded False` is `Monad m => m a -> m a`.  Then how is it possible that my first definition of `guarded` type-checks?

Comment: AFAIK, `fail` is deprecated since it is not suitable for use in all monads. Use `mzero` from `Control.Monad`'s `MonadPlus` typeclass.

Comment: @AJFarmar indeed RWH recommend not using fail because, unless you know how it's implemented in all the monads your code touches, it can fail.  Yet, my question is more about type-checking: notice that `fail "..."` appears to type-check with both `Monad m => m a` and `Monad m => m a -> m a`.

Comment: It's using the monad instance for `(->) r`, in this case with `r ~ m a`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're being tripped up by the controversial *function monad instance* (actually this is not that controversial in the Haskell community, but I personally think we might have been better off if it didn't exist) together with the uncontroversially broken `fail` method.

Look at the types:

```
guarded False
   = fail "skipped" :: m a -> m a
   ≡ (fail :: String -> (m a -> m a)) "skipped"
   ≡ (fail :: String -> F (m a)) "skipped"    -- with `type F x = m a -> x`
```

I.e., you calling `fail` on the `(->) (m a)` monad, and that [does not define a custom `fail` implementation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-804), so it [defaults to the error one](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#fail)

```
  fail        :: String -> ((->) r) a
  fail s      = errorWithoutStackTrace s
```

Note how this even typechecks if you remove the `Monad m` constraint from your function, because *the `fail` doesn't use that monad*.

The correct generalisation of your function is

```
guarded :: Alternative f => Bool -> f a -> f a
guarded True = id
guarded False = const empty
```

This does *not* typecheck if I erronously forget the `const`, because functions are not an instance of `Alternative`.